# MYSQL about variables

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total 
    FROM ".$datatable."
    WHERE STATE=".$category ;
```

Im trying to figure out why this isnt working.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total 
    FROM ".$datatable."
    WHERE STATE='AL'" ;
```

this one hwoever works. Im unsure of what concactinate or " ' syntax issue it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include single quotation marks for the `where` statement. Also, since you're using double quotes you don't actually need to escape from the string to include the PHP variables.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total FROM $datatable WHERE STATE='$category'";
```